# Obtain a language name in different languages

Tags: c#, .net, localization, internationalization, cultureinfo

I have the following:

```
if (currentUICulture.Equals(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")))
    _EnglishLabel = "Anglais";
else
    _EnglishLabel = "English";
```

ask myself if this code can be optimized for an arbitrary number of current cultures.

I could try to get that for the current UI culture, like this:

```
_EnglishLabel = new CultureInfo("en-US").DisplayName;
```

but what if I should give the English language not by the `currentUICulture`, but an arbitrary culture passed as parameter...

in other words, how to get the

```
new CultureInfo("en-US").GetDisplayName(myArbitraryCulture);
```

PS.

The .NET Framework code

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  DisplayName
//
//  Returns the full name of the CultureInfo in the localized language.
//  For example, if the localized language of the runtime is Spanish and the CultureInfo is
//  US English, "Ingles (Estados Unidos)" will be returned.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public virtual String DisplayName
{
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.Assert(m_name != null, "[CultureInfo.DisplayName]Always expect m_name to be set");

        return m_cultureData.SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  GetNativeName
//
//  Returns the full name of the CultureInfo in the native language.
//  For example, if the CultureInfo is US English, "English
//  (United States)" will be returned.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public virtual String NativeName {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        return (this.m_cultureData.SNATIVEDISPLAYNAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: C# has Dictionaries, doesn't it? Seems like the obvious approach to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, that is not about dictionaries, that is about the CultureInfo embedded and self contained information about the language names... I hoped I don't need at all to use custom strings to translate English in other languages, as it is already done in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve translations for *installed* framework languages. The workings are undocumented but the internal implementations can be seen in the reference source (e.g. for [CultureData](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/globalization/culturedata.cs#L1192)).
For target cultures other than installed ones, the English fallback will be returned.

Building on top of that we can use the following (again, for installed framework languages only):

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this CultureInfo culture, CultureInfo locale)
{
    var rm = new ResourceManager("mscorlib", typeof(object).Assembly);
    var resourceKey = $"Globalization.ci_{culture.Name}";
    return rm.GetString(resourceKey, locale);
}
```

For example with Swedish and English installed:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
var swedishName = culture.GetDisplayName(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv")); // Engelska
var englishName = culture.GetDisplayName(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")); // English
var germanName = culture.GetDisplayName(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de")); // English <- German not installed
```

To cover all languages (or an arbitrary collection of languages), I would suggest a non-native approach as the built-in way is not really supporting your use case.

Cheers!

Comment: so, there's no universal solution for that... We need to install languages on the server before use this solution, and the dynamic adding of languages is not possible

Comment: No, nothing out-of-the-box so to speak. The NuGet package IsoNames (which seems abandoned and has only net45 support) does what you're after. It's basically a bunch of dictionaries just for looking up country names and language names per culture.